# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/R$style

Tags: android, makefile, facebook-android-sdk, android-source

I tried to integrated [Facebook Android SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk/4.25.0)(4.25.0) into my app. Everything worked fine if I used Gradle build in Android Studio.

It didn't work if I integrated with my AOSP(Android open source project) source code. There is no compile error. but when I call

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
 //if I didn't call this method, it gave me another exception said 
 'The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call 
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.'
```

I got below exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/R$style;
 at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.<clinit>(FacebookSdk.java:84)
```

My mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/gridlayout/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/design/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/cardview/res

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES := facebook-android-sdk

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
         facebook-android-sdk:libs/facebook-android-sdk-4.25.1.aar \
         bolts-android:libs/bolts-android-1.4.0.jar
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It indicated where the exception came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also run into this error most of the times I add 3rd party libs to an AOSP app build. What usually works is the following:

1) "convert" your .aar to a .jar (extract it, rename the classes.jar to facebook-android-sdk-4.25.1.jar, copy the res folder somewhere you can link to.)

2) add the following to your .mk file:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += facebook-android
...
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --extra-packages com.facebook
...
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += /path/to/facebook-android-sdk-RES/
...
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += facebook-android:/path/to/the/facebook-android-sdk-4.25.1.jar
```

3) add all dependcies to the build (appcompat, gridlayout, customtabs, etc. the link to the facebook-sdk you posted shows them.)

---

I am not sure if you can skip the first step since it depends on your android version ([Link to the commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/2902d4585f2a60a91084e96d00f2ee8d8301bf65%5E!/)). I am on older versions where `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES` does not exist(But you dont get an error if you still use it).

But your error message `Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/R$style` indicates me that thats also the case for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this issue:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES := facebook-android-sdk
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS :=\
      --auto-add-overlay \
      --extra-packages com.facebook
```

It worked like a charm.

Thanks,